# Optimizing two queries which aim at getting only the min row on a grouping key

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm not sure I can get a clear question name...

What I want is to calculate the distance between points and polygons (this is step 1 and then, for each point, get only the closest polygon (nb : one polygon can have many points attached, but one point must be attached to only one polygon).

I'm currently doing is the following :

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS
    SELECT 
        areas.*
        points.* -- includes a points_id column
        ST_DistanceSphere(areas.geometry, points.geometry) AS distance_sphere

        FROM points
        INNER JOIN areas
        ON  st_DWithin(areas.geometry, points.geometry, 25) 


    SELECT *
     FROM
     (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY temp_table.points_id ORDER BY distance_sphere ASC) as rownumber, *
         FROM temp_table
     ) X 
     WHERE rownumber = 1
```

I have a feeling it's quite inefficient (the first request has been processing all night, on a 4 000 000 rows database... It took 29mn with a `limit 10` at the end) as it's calculating many useless rows.

Would putting the first request in the second one be faster ?

```
    SELECT *
     FROM
     (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY temp_table.points_id ORDER BY distance_sphere ASC) as rownumber, *
         FROM (
            SELECT 
            areas.*
            points.* -- includes a points_id column
            ST_DistanceSphere(areas.geometry, points.geometry) AS distance_sphere
            FROM areas
            INNER JOIN points
            ON  st_DWithin(areas.geometry, points.geometry, 25)
         )
     ) X 
     WHERE rownumber = 1
```

If not, how could I optimize what I'm doing ?

Comment: You could start by adding the table structures (including indexes) and the query plans(s) to your question.

Comment: show us your geometry epsg/srid for geometry columns - use st_srid(geometry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What EPSG/SRID do you use (degree, meters) for example:
 - 4326 is in degrees
 - 3857 is in meters

If you use meteric then you should use st_distance not st_distancesphere. If you use degree EPSG then be carefull with st_dwithin as this using units of EPSG so 25 means 25 degree and that is HUGE distance (around 3000 km).
So if you use 4326 (degree) then for your st_dwithin use much smaller value then 25.

Create gist indexes on both geometry columns.

```
Create index on point using gist(geometry);
Create index on areas using gist(geometry);
```

And just use your question with proposed changes.(change st_distancesphare to st_distance or use st_dwithin with much smaller value).

Comment: Indeed, it was 4326, which explains the time taken (I'm basically making a cross join in my first query). Thanks. Is there a way to change from degrees to meters ?

Comment: Yes you can upodate your epsg/srid with function for example st_transform(geometry,3857) .

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to be sure, if I'm in 3857, then `st_dwithin(geometryA_3857, geometryB_3857, 25)` will mean 25 meters, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is 25 meters.